# How can I determine what hosting provider hosts a site?

Tags: web-hosting

Is there a service that will identify where a site is hosted (presumably by IP)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A good place to start is whois:

[ARIN IP Address whois lookup](http://ws.arin.net/whois/): this allows you to see who "owns" (ie. who is the registered operator for) a given IP address block.

[Internic whois lookup](http://www.internic.net/whois.html): this looks up the registered operator of a given domain name, along with their DNS servers (which *may* be operated by their hosting provider, but which could also easily be hosted elsewhere).

That will get you started. For more detailed information, use the traceroute command (or "tracert" on Windows) to see the path between your point on the network, and theirs.

Comment: The nameserver data from whois seems to be a better indicator of the hosting provider than the domain owner/operator.

Comment: Absolutely, but again, you should definitely take it with a large grain of salt: just because the website is hosted with a particular provider, doesn't mean the DNS is hosted by them as well.

I'd typically defer to the ARIN lookup data if you're primarily interested in the (web/application) hosting provider, as well as the traceroute information.

Answer (score 5):

Can't believe no one mentioned [Netcraft](http://news.netcraft.com/)

"What's that site running?" Top left hand corner.

Comment: works really nice +1 thx

Comment: Can't find this option anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This will also depend on whether the domain is owned and registered by the hosting provider or not. The best clue normally is the DNS records, however I used to roll my own DNS for a while using zone edit for example, and non of the domain queries would show who is hosting the domain.

However it should give you fairly accurate information as to who owns the domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this website: http://www.quarkbase.com it will give you what you need plus many other info.

Comment: Quarkbase seems to be down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use our service [Who is Hosting this Site?](https://www.accuwebhosting.com/resources/who-is-hosting-this)

Some points to keep in mind ...

- If a website is hosted on a server farm (data center), then Who is
  Hosting this? will likely be showing the name of the data center and
  the web hosting company hosting this website.
- When your site is using services like CloudFlare, it is difficult to 
  find out the actual hosting provider.    Accuracy level is 99%.
- Benefits: Free utility, display who is the hosting provider, domain
  ownership and who is records.